# ChromeDriver deleteAllCookies() throws exception

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I am using the same **Chrome version 55**, along with **ChromeDriver 2.26**. Trying to perform webdriver.manage().deleteAllCookies() will throw the following

> exception: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error:
>   Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context':
>   {"auxData":{"frameId":"4064.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"nam‌​e":"","origin":"://"‌​}

This exception wasn't thrown for previous versions of Chrome and **ChromeDriver**. Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same regression.

I could fix it by updating Chrome (last version is 62.0.3202.75) and the Chromedriver (last version is 2.33).